# C# invoking unmanaged DLL: Bad_allocation exception thrown in DLL

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged-memory

I have been tasked to update a legacy 32-bit C# application to support converting 4K/UHD images (jpg, tiff, etc.) to an YUV image for further processing. The way we have accomplish converting SD/HD content is by using a DLL in order to invoke an open source tool, FFmpeg, to perform the operation. This is accomplish by doing the following:

1. C# application passes the image file to the DLL
2. DLL then allocates the required memory needed to capture the new converted image (bytes per frame => 1080p=8.2mb, 2160p=33.2mb)
3. DLL then invokes 3rd party tool by passing in pointer to file and the allocated memory buffer
4. Once the function call returns, we save the converted image to a file
5. Cleanup (closing files, deallocating memory, etc.)
6. DLL returns true/false boolean whether it was successful or not.

Anyhow, there is a LOT more to it, but that is it in a nutshell. The problem I am having is after updating the DLL to support 4K/UHD by allocating 33mb, I now get a System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException; using the VS debugger, I observed a bad_allocation exception on this unmanaged C++ line

`UInt32 *pixGroupFrameBuf = new UInt32[bytesPerFrameHdr/BYTES_PER_INPUT_PIXEL];  //Where UInt32[bytesPerFrameHdr/BYTES_PER_INPUT_PIXEL] is 33177600 bytes=>33mb`

If I convert a 1080p jpg image, it works as its only allocates 8mb. If I convert my 4K jpg image to 1080 YUV image, which also only allocates 8mb, it works too; so its not my passed in source file. After some experiments, issue become intermittent when I attempt to allocate 28mb and throws exceptions pass 30mb. Looking at my available Free memory under the Windows Resource Monitor tool I see my system has about 4GB left.

Additionally, because our legacy C# application is very large GUI application, I decided to create a much simpler 32-bit C# application that only invokes the DLL in the same way so I can debug faster and better pinpoint the problem. What I found is my new C# project just works. I can even bump the allocation to much larger amounts and it allocates the requested size without an issue (as long as i keep it under 2GB and have enough Free memory available). Therefore, the problem lies with our much larger C# GUI application invoking the DLL.

With that I am stumped to understand what is going on with our legacy C# application and what to try next. Any chance somebody may have an idea of what could be happening or suggest what I could look at or try next?

...Here is a picture of my system resource so you can see the memory usage between my two C# applications. *_Menu.vshost.exe is our legacy app. convert.vshost.exe is my test app. As you can see our legacy C# is bigger, but not gigabytes bigger.
[image: SystemResource]
[image: TaskManager]

Final Notes:

1. I am not open to convert the 32-bit C# application to 64-bit. I know its old and should be updated, but that's too big of effort to do at the moment. Also, I believe have proven it's not a 32-bit problem since my test application works.
2. I am open to allocate memory within the C# application and pass it into the DLL for it to use instead of allocating within. That is my backup plan if I can't resolve it as designed.
3. I don't believe I have a memory leak within DLL as I have profile it using Resharper dotMemory
4. If you can't help, thanks for just being open to get this far!

Comment: If it matters... `UInt32 *pixGroupFrameBuf = new UInt32[bytesPerFrameHdr]` tries to allocate 4 * 33177600 bytes, not 33MB...

Comment: A program does not fail like that because of a lack of RAM or there isn't enough free memory available.  A 32-bit app has a 2GB address space and needs to find room for code and data.  The failure mode is not finding enough *contiguous* address space.  The chunk you need is fairly large, after a program has been running for a while the address space gets fragmented and there just isn't a big enough hole left.  Needing more than ~90MB then gets risky.  Still, the commit size is quite small, bad_alloc can also trip when the unmanaged heap got corrupted.  May the good Lord have mercy then.

Comment: @ paulsm4 Good eye. That's what I get for trying to make my code snippet more presentable. I just updated my original post. Sorry to cause that confusion.

Comment: @Hans Passant I see what you are saying about needing it to be contiguous. As you can see from my pic I have less than 400mb free mem left in my example. Your explanation makes sense and it aligns with what I read on other stackoverflow post. However, something I also noticed is after I get bad_alloc exception from the legacy app, I then run the same image through my test app and it works. That part confuses me. Because if I indeed don't have 33mb of contiguous mem available then the test app should have fail too.

Comment: ...With that, is there any API call I can do within the unmanaged C++ DLL to determine if I have enough contiguous mem w/out attempting to allocate?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was moving the memory allocation from being in the function to defining a global block. Instead of allocating/deallocating a block of memory for every image I converted, I changed it to use/reuse a global block (set to the max size possible). Granted, I know I can still obtain a bad_alloc if I don't have a contiguous block at construction. However, I believe this change works for me because I am not losing my 33MB contiguous block the next time I need it. My guess of what was happening - the Windows Memory Manager took my contiguous block after I freed it and eventually put me in a situation in which the next time needed a 33MB block, there wasn't anything contiguous. Hope this explanation helps someone in future.